# Is there a C++20 way to detect if a type is an instantiation of a template using just concepts and requires()?

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts

For many years, I always used the following piece of code to detect if an arbitrary type is a template instantiation:

```cpp
namespace priv {
    template <typename, template <typename...> typename>
    struct _is_instance_impl : public std::false_type {};

    template <template <typename...> typename U, typename...Ts>
    struct _is_instance_impl<U<Ts...>, U> : public std::true_type {};
}

template <typename T, template <typename ...> typename U>
using is_instance = priv::_is_instance_impl<std::decay_t<T>, U>;
```

This also works fine with C++20 concepts:

```cpp
template <typename T, template <typename ...> typename U>
concept instance_of = priv::_is_instance_impl<std::decay_t<T>, U>::value;

template <typename T>
std::size_t len_of(T &&s) requires instance_of<T, std::basic_string> {
        return s.length();
}
```

I have attempted to replace this SFINAE-based code with a C++20 `requires()` expression, without luck.

Has anyone any idea on how this could be accomplished, if it is actually possible at all?

Comment: I think `instance_of` could be problematic sometimes. For example, `std::vector<bool>` is an instance of `std::vector`, so...

Comment: "I have attempted to replace this SFINAE-based code with a C++20 requires() expression" - there's nothing "SFINAE-based" about that code, and a `requires` expression would very much be "SFINAE-based" anyway. There's nothing "bad" about your current approach that needs to be replaced.

Comment: @Barry yes, my bad. I couldn't find a satisfying way to describe what can be referred as "what we all used before concepts", so I have written that without realizing that `requires` is indeed still SFINAE. 

I asked this question mostly because, even though I know the older approach is still fine, I was curious if there was a newer way to achieve the same, maybe with something less "arcane" than that (even though I am quite used reading those SFINAE incantations nowadays...).

Comment: @mcilloni: It's been my experience that most of the time someone wants to ask if a type is an instance of some template, what they *really* want is something more general. For example, if you have a function that you want to constrain on taking some `vector`, it might be more reasonable to constrain it on `contiguous_range`, thereby allowing far more types.

Answer (score 5):

Without helper, the closest I succeed to get is:

```
template <class T, template <typename...> class C>
concept test = requires (T t)
{
    {[] <typename... Ts>(C<Ts...>& c) -> C<Ts...>& { return c; }(t)} -> std::same_as<T&>;

    // simplified version, but allows conversion
    //[] <typename... Ts>(C<Ts...>&) {}(t);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Eaf7GGKaW) which is not accepted by clang though.

Comment: Even if that was accepted, that version also allows implicit conversion to `C<Ts...>` when passing `T` to the immediately invoked lambda expression. **edit** or does the marking the parameter as an lvalue reference prevent that? Maybe you're right.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: there is the additional constraint that `std::same_as<T&, C<Ts>&>` which should fix that

Comment: Oh I forgot that `std::same_as` was also populated with `C<Ts...>&`, that makes sense.